# Will the YU-GI-OH! card copyright ever end?

Tags: copyright, public-domain

Day by day they bring out new cards, I wonder if someday the royalties will end and if so when approximately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It will end

Each card has its own copyright. Using the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states) as the basis, because most countries mimic them, the copyright for a published work with a known author ends approximately 70 years after the death of the author or 95 years from publication for company-owned copyrights.

The Yu-Gi-Oh manga was first published in 1996 and [its author died in 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuki_Takahashi), so the underlying manga will enter the Public Domain in 2093.

The card game consists of three elements: the cards themselves, the artwork on them and the rules. The rules **aren't** copyrighted. The artwork's copyright is tied to the artists making it, if it is licensed art, or the company, when it is work-for-hire, so might or might lapse at two points: 70 years after the artist's death or together with the card. The card's copyright in the compilation lapses 95 years after the publication. The first set of Yu-Gi-Oh cards was published in 1999, so the copyright will lapse at the earliest 2095 on the first card set. But **only** that first card set. Other card sets will enter Public Domain when their 95 years are up.

Comment: Specifically what copyright does "the cards themselves" have? so the last card released from Yu-Gi-Oh! this year in 2022 will be in the public domain after 95 years?

Comment: The card is what's known as a compilation - Artwork, frame, rules text, icons, name, fluff text.... everything in a whole package. That package in **that** combination on a 2022 card will enter PD in 2098.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

Japanese copyright expires 70 years after the death of the author.

[Kazuki Takahashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazuki_Takahashi) sadly passed in 2022. Copyright in everything he authored will expire 1 January 2093. Anything authored by others will have a different expiry.

Comment: that's for the manga, not the cards, which were made by the Konami, first published in 1999