# YU-GI-OH! name IP protection?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, trademark, patents

What is the TM and IP status for **Yugioh**?

Related to question [Will the YU-GI-OH! card copyright ever end?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/87619/3942), is the name 'Yu-Gi-Oh!' name protected?

This resource [Justia](https://trademarks.justia.com/769/77/yu-gi-76977902.html) suggests TM protection for video game use.  I'm wondering about other game formats and merchandising?

Comment: https://www.uspto.gov/trademarks/search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's trademarked.

Yu-Gi-Oh has active trademarks in at least the following categories:

- [IC 041 - US 100, 101, 107](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=76977902&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch) Providing games played through communication by computer terminals; providing computer game software programs that are downloaded through computer networks, providing a computer game that may be accessed network-wide by network users
- [IC 041 - US 100, 101, 107](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=76977468&caseSearchType=US_APPLICATION&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch) Providing games played through communication by computer terminals; providing computer game software programs that are downloaded through computer networks, providing a computer game that may be accessed network-wide by network users

So **any** downloadable or internet-streamed game is covered.

- [IC 009 - US 021, 023, 026, 036, 038](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=76071879&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch) Computer products, namely, computer game programs; [ video game cartridges; video game CD-ROMs; video output game units; computer game CD-ROMS;] video game programs; video game programs for use with television sets [; video game machines for use with television sets; game-playing equipment, namely, joysticks and game controllers ]

Any data-carriers sold are covered here. CDs, Cartridges, SD-cards. Together with the 041 trademark: **Any and all computer game is covered.**

- [IC 016 - US 002, 005, 022, 023, 029, 037, 038, 050](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=76071881&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch) Playing cards; trading cards [ ; calendars; posters; game instruction manuals; computer game instruction manuals; game instructions sheets; scoring sheets; books, namely, strategy guides; stationery ].

Almost all print products are covered here.

- [IC 041 - US 100, 101, 107](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=87501573&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch): Entertainment services, namely, an ongoing series featuring animated cartoons provided through webcasts.

Animation series are covered here.

### They covered all their bases

The most extensive trademark under the Yu-Gi-Oh sub-items covers all of this, including pretty much any merchandize you could think of and that is not food:

- [IC 009, 016, 018, 025, 028, 041 - US 001, 002, 003, 005, 021, 022, 023, 026, 029, 036, 037, 038, 039, 041, 050, 100, 101, 107](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=88925847&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch) - Straps for mobile phones; accessories for mobile phones, namely, earphones, phone cases; mouse pads; integrated circuit cards and smart cards, namely, pre-recorded DVDs and CDs featuring computer programs for playing video and computer games; downloadable computer programs for video and computer games via communication networks; downloadable computer game programs; downloadable computer game programs for games adapted for use with an external display screen or monitor; downloadable video game programs via communication networks for computer games adapted for use with an external display screen or monitor; downloadable audio recordings featuring music via communication networks; exposed cinematographic films; exposed slide films; slide film mounts; recorded video discs, video tapes, DVDs, and CD-ROMs featuring animated cartoons and animation, and featuring movies in the field of adventure and children's entertainment; downloadable image files via the internet featuring animated cartoons and animation; downloadable electronic publications in the nature of books and magazines in the field of comics, cartoons, games, music, movies and toys; computer game programs for arcade games adapted for use with an external display screen or monitor; spectacles; sunglasses; downloadable electronic publications in the nature of comic books and magazines in the field of comics and cartoons, Notebooks for writing; paper; stationery; postcards; rubber erasers; seals for stationery; stickers for stationery; writing instruments; bookmarkers; writing pads; pen and pencil cases; posters; collectible trading cards; books and comic books featuring cartoons and children's stories; calendars; diaries; printed matter, namely, posters, brochures, and newsletters in the field of comics; electric pencil sharpeners; luncheon mats of paper; towels of paper; handkerchiefs of paper; pastes and adhesives for stationery or household use; comic books featuring cartoons and children's stories, All-purpose carrying bags; tote bags; handbags; waist bags; shoulder bags; backpacks; Boston bags; carry-on bags; school bags; travelling bags; wallets; key cases; commutation-ticket holders, namely, ticket pouches; business card cases; leather pouches; pouches for holding keys; drawstring pouches; pouches of textile; pouches for holding makeup, keys and other personal items; umbrellas; parasols; walking sticks; canes; clothing for domestic pets; envelopes of leather for packaging, Clothing, namely, jeans; jackets; pants; coats; sweaters; sport shirts; polo shirts; shirts; blouses; shirts for suits; sweatsuits; pajamas; nightwear; underwear; swimwear; swimming caps; T-shirts; sleep masks; aprons; socks and stockings; shawls; scarves; gloves; mittens; neckties; neckerchiefs; bandanas; under garments; mufflers as neck scarves; ear muffs; hoods; nightcaps; headwear; footwear, not for sports; shoes; boots; masquerade costumes; garters; suspenders; waistbands; belts for clothing; clothes for sports, namely, jerseys; footwear for sports, namely, athletic footwear, Computer game consoles for use with an external display screen or monitor; hand-held games with liquid crystal displays; toys, namely, action figures, dolls, puzzle games, and dominoes; playing cards; trading card games; cards for trading card games; coin-operated amusement machines and apparatus for use in amusement parks other than arcade video game machines; playing card game accessories, namely, playing card cases, playing card holders, mats for use in connection with playing card games, playing card shuffling devices and dice; jigsaw puzzles, Educational and instructional services, namely, providing classes, panel discussions, and seminars in the field of arts, crafts, sports, comics, and entertainment; arranging, conducting, and organizing game events, namely, card game competitions; providing non-downloadable electronic books and electronic comics in the field of cartoons, games, movies, and toys via communication networks; on-line reference library services, namely, providing electronic library services which feature electronic books, comics, pictures, and images via an on-line computer network; reference libraries of literature and documentary records; entertainment services, namely, provision of online non-downloadable comic books and graphic novels; movie showing, movie film production, and movie film distribution; entertainment services, namely, providing non-downloadable sound recordings featuring music via internet or mobile phone communications; providing non-downloadable games via communications by computer terminals or mobile phone communications; providing amusement facilities; entertainment services, namely, an ongoing series featuring animated cartoons provided through webcasts

### Not enough?

Oh, and as a kicker: Yu-Gi-Oh *might* be considered a [famous mark](https://www.inta.org/topics/famous-well-known-marks/), similar to Apple computers, Nintendo or Microsoft: hearing the word immediately gives people the idea of a very specific Anime card game with larger than life series attached to it.

Giant Food, Inc. v. Nation's Foodservices, Inc., 710 F.2d 1565, 218 U.S.P.Q. 390 (Fed. Cir. 2004) held that the mark GIANT FOOD was famous because:

- 45 years of use
- extensive media exposure
- sales in excess of 1 billion USD per year
- prominent display on the facade of supermarkets

Yu-Gi-Oh can claim:

- 24 years of use
- Extensive media exposure (dozens of Anime series, cinema movies...)
- Konami's '22 revenue of 2.8 Billion USD (~300 billion Yen) was largely due to Yu-Gi-Oh  and in the 22 years some reporter claimed that *1 trillion Yen* would have been earned by Yu-Gi-Oh
- prominent ads for any of the merchandize and series, such as partnerships with McDonalds.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer.  I'd like to call a game something like 'Yugioh104' and distribute rules for a Yugioh based game that can be played with two decks of 52 regular playing cards.  In my scanning of the their wide ranging claims it sounds like the famous mark would be their strongest.  What do you think?

Comment: @StephanLuis Konami is Litigious and would surely love to sue someone stepping on their trademarks.

Comment: Great advice! We'll think of another name.  Maybe something like 'AnimeShark' , where TM search is 'clear'.